# Big difference in run time for two machines - how to handle?

Tags: python, performance

I have a script i wrote (its pretty long so i wont paste it unless you would like to)
maybe its not the most efficient code - it does some kind of bfs on certain data that been held in a dict.

The major issue is that I wrote it on my PC and tested it with the regular python 2.7 version I have installed, but it will running on a server that is supposed to have much better performance over my PC. However it's running X4 times **slower** on the server and its really interesting why (measured time of running with time()).

I need to write some more on this scripts for my research and run them on large data sets and I wish to know how to resolve the performance issue.

Maybe I need higher priority in the UNIX machine or something?

Thanks,
Tomer

Windows = Intel Core 2 Quad CPU @2.66Ghz - 4GbRam with 64bit windows 7

UNIX = 16 processors of Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7320  @ 2.13GHz with 64GB RAM

Comment: Does the server use another version of python than your PC?

Comment: Windows != PC, PC can run Windows, Unix, Linux, Solaris if you want to. Just to clairify. Also note that cPython is single-threaded, the number of cores won't matter much. The speed however of each individiual core is what ultimately will affect your performance. Seeing how 2.66Ghz is faster than 2.13Ghz, i'd say there's your answer. Also we know nothing about what's runnign on the server, what the code looks like or how you've configured both machines.

Comment: From the specs you give, actually the Windows CPU is faster (2.66GHz vs 2.13GHz). And probably you can get better understanding of your problem if you also learn how to properly use punctuations.

Comment: i didnt thought about it this way, so if i will use threads it might be resolve my issue?

Comment: Either IO performance is your bottleneck (disk reads/writes) or you may use modules that are optimized for consumer-type Intel processors and don't sit that well with Xeon. There can be a huge difference in performance between using repository version and building it with Intel compiler for native execution (but it is a lot of hassle).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your code, (It will be good if you paste it and others will tell you code optimizations.) but definitely you can do following things,

1. there can be 2 possibilities, either one of the method/statement/module is slow or whole code is slow.
   check that by adding logger statements and find out culprit/time taking method. if possible tune it or improve it.
2. As you said, your code is not optimal well then make it optimal (paste it here if you find culprit method, experts will suggest you on that). optimal code isn't a magic.
3. Same code can take different execution times on different OSes/platform because of platform changes/implementations. before you directly run, have a look at the setting and tunings possible.
4. If you have such powerful processing power (quad core) then try utilizing it by making your code suitable for it (use multithreading, parallel execution, efficient data structures etc.)

That will help you, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks , i will try use threads in my code and see whats comes up